# python for large data processing

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, queue, multiprocessing

I relatively new to python, and have been able to answer most of my questions based on similar problems answered on forms, but I'm at a point where I'm stuck an could use some help.

I have a simple nested for loop script that generates an output of strings. What I need to do next is have each grouping go through a simulation, based on numerical values that the strings will be matched too.

really my question is how do I go about this in the best way? Im not sure if multithreading will work since the strings are generated and then need to undergo the simulation, one set at a time. I was reading about queue's and wasn't sure if they could be passed into queue's for storage and then undergo the simulation, in the same order they entered the queue.

Regardless of the research I've done I'm open to any suggestion anyone can make on the matter.

thanks!

edit: Im not look for an answer on how to do the simulation, but rather a way to store the combinations while simulations are being computed

example

```
X = ["a","b"]
Y = ["c","d","e"]
Z= ["f","g"]

for A in itertools.combinations(X,1):
    for B in itertools.combinations(Y,2):
        for C in itertools.combinations(Z, 2):

        D = A + B + C
        print(D)
```

Comment: Code example would be good.

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do? Real code example / desired output? What simulations are you doing? Why is this related to "large data"?

Comment: The code is like this, its finding all combinations of three lists, this is not a school project and i cannot post the exact code for it, but the lists are extremely large.  the values in D would be matched to other numerical values and then undergo the simulation
thanks, dan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The simulations are monte carlo, as of now it can just be an average for now. What im trying to solve is time, I could do the simulations right after the combination is found, however I would like the code to continue finding combinations, while it does a simulation for a combination found earlier.

Comment: lol that was pretty foolish of me

Comment: I think the nesting on your code example is incorrect

Comment: I don't understand. What does this code snippet mean? Where's the simulation process? What are you trying to store? Mind modify your code to make these clear?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The problem is not clear and thus it is unclear whether multi-threading is applicable or not. To save memory, seems like you should use a generator (lookup 'yield' in the docs) to generate values, then loop over the generator, doing your simulations and recording the results.

Comment: @RobertB, i am sorry for it being unclear, its hard to explain my problem, but I will try here....The code finds combinations I need, Once a combination is found I need to run a simulation (I dont need help with how to do a simulation). What I need to do is temporarily store the combinations, in order that they are found. I would like to have a simulation script, that pulls the combinations, one at a time so that i can then run a simulation. Ideally I would like to have python continue to find the combinations, while a simulations are being computed.

Comment: @RobertB if I had the program get one combination, and then run the simulation, it would take a tremendous amount of time. I would like to shave off time by doing both "simultaneously" essentially. Im not sure if this is even feasible or not. I assuming that python would need to be ran on multiple cores to do this if it is possible. let me know if this is still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Muktithreading wont speed things up. Look at the 'multiprocessing' module.

Comment: @RobertB thanks ill check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was hinted at in the comments, the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#) module is what you're looking for. Threading won't help you because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which limits execution to one Python thread at a time. In particular, I would look at [multiprocessing pools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool). These objects give you an interface to have a pool of subprocesses do work for you in parallel with the main process, and you can go back and check on the results later.

Your example snippet could look something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

X = ["a","b"]
Y = ["c","d","e"]
Z= ["f","g"]

pool = multiprocessing.pool() # by default, this will create a number of workers equal to
                 # the number of CPU cores you have available
combination_list = [] # create a list to store the combinations

for A in itertools.combinations(X,1):
    for B in itertools.combinations(Y,2):
        for C in itertools.combinations(Z, 2):

        D = A + B + C
        combination_list.append(D) # append this combination to the list

results = pool.map(simulation_function, combination_list)
# simulation_function is the function you're using to actually run your
# simulation - assuming it only takes one parameter: the combination
```

The call to `pool.map` is blocking - meaning that once you call it, execution in the main process will halt until all the simulations are complete, but it is running them in parallel. When they complete, whatever your simulation function returns will be available in `results`, in the same order that the input arguments were in the `combination_list`.

If you don't want to wait for them, you can also use [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) on your pool and store the result to look at later:

```
import multiprocessing

X = ["a","b"]
Y = ["c","d","e"]
Z= ["f","g"]

pool = multiprocessing.pool()
result_list = [] # create a list to store the simulation results

for A in itertools.combinations(X,1):
    for B in itertools.combinations(Y,2):
        for C in itertools.combinations(Z, 2):

        D = A + B + C
        result_list.append(pool.apply_async(
                simulation_function,
                args=(D,))) # note the extra comma - args must be a tuple

# do other stuff
# now iterate over result_list to check the results when they're ready
```

If you use this structure, `result_list` will be full of [multiprocessing.AsyncResult objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult), which allow you to check if they are ready with `result.ready()` and, if it's ready, retrieve the result with `result.get()`. This approach will cause the simulations to be kicked off right when the combination is calculated, instead of waiting until all of them have been calculated to start processing them. The downside is that it's a little more complicated to manage and retrieve the results. For example, you have to make sure the result is ready or be ready to catch an exception, you need to be ready to catch exceptions that may have been raised in the worker function, etc. The caveats are explained pretty well in the documentation.

If calculating the combinations doesn't actually take very long and you don't mind your main process halting until they're all ready, I suggest the `pool.map` approach.

Comment: @djk47463 I see you're pretty new to Stack Overflow. Welcome! I just wanted to let you know about the "Accept" option - there's a hollow checkmark underneath the vote count on answers to your questions. When you ask a question, you may accept one of the answers as the one that was most helpful to you by clicking the check mark on that answer. There shouldn't be any pressure to do this if none of the answers addressed your question to your satisfaction, but if one does, it is good etiquette to accept it. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer